# Enqueue scripts based on options

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, options, customization

What is the best method to enqueue scripts based on options I have? Let's say I have 50 options and for each I need to enqueue a script(some of them might repeat.). Can I have any problems(performance, etc.) if I do this in a `foreach` loop and `switch` to detect what script I need? Do you think is better than calling all scripts no matter what options I have? Like so(the class works just like I need):

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    var $options;

    public function __construct($options){
        $this->options = ( isset($options) ) ? $options : array();
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'enqueue') );
    }

    //This is the section where I enqueue the scripts
    function enqueue() {
        foreach ($this->options as $value) {
            switch ($value['type']) {
                case 'value1':
                    wp_enqueue_script('value1_script');
                    break;
                case 'value2':
                    wp_enqueue_script('value2_script');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    function render_opts() {
        $output = '';
        foreach ($this->options as $value) {
            switch ($value['type']) {
                case 'value1':
                    $output .= 'value1';
                    break;
                case 'value2':
                    $output .= 'value2';
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: A foreach cycle through 50 items will **not** affect performance. But if you enqueue 50 scripts in a page with 50 different `<script>` tags, the page require 50 http requests to load and this will sure affect performance.

Comment: If those are all some tiny scripts, I'd go with lamzozo's suggestion. However, if some scripts are big, I'd load them conditionally. I personally like the Jedi Master Way: http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

Answer (score 2):

I would combine and minify all the scripts, in this case you don't have to update your php code if you add more options or scripts.